# Why my ad manager doesn't work with prebid.js

Tags: google-ad-manager, prebid.js, prebid, header-bidding

I really need your help with prebid.js. I have already read a lot of information about it, but there are still questions.

**What I need to do**: add an advertise block (div) on my website.

**What I've done**:

1. downloaded the prebid.js file with several advertising providers
   from here http://prebid.org/download.html
2. registered the site with GoogleAdManager
3. following this video http://prebid.org/adops/step-by-step.html

   - created 'line item' 200*200
   - create 'creative' and pass code from the video

.

```
<script>
   try {
     window.top.pbjs.renderAd(document, '%%PATTERN:hb_adid%%');
   } catch (e) {}
</script>
```

(actually there are another code under the video and I don't know which is correct but have already tried both)

```
    <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prebid-universal-creative@latest/dist/creative.js"></script>
    <script>
      var ucTagData = {};
      ucTagData.adServerDomain = "";
      ucTagData.pubUrl = "%%PATTERN:url%%";
      ucTagData.targetingMap = %%PATTERN:TARGETINGMAP%%;
      ucTagData.hbPb = "%%PATTERN:hb_pb%%";

      try {
        ucTag.renderAd(document, ucTagData);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    </script>
```

- follow all other steps

  4. after that I go to AdManager -> ad units -> select my unit -> tag,
     then copy these two pieces of code to my site
     [image: AdManager -> ad units -> select my unit -> tag]
  5. deploy changes

And after all when I opened my site I saw my block with advertise in it.

**What is the problem?** 
I think that  it this advertise is provided not by Prebid.js but by GoogleAdSense because when I switch to debug mode ('?pbjs_debug=true' to site url)
  the only thing that I found is:

```
    Prebid INFO: Prebid.js v3.2.0 loaded
    amp-inabox.js:132 Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1912050130240 https://www.[mysite].com/prebid?pbjs_debug=true
```

Tere are no logs about bid requests and bid responces. I think that it's because of wrong code in my 'creative' but it is provided by official site...

Please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Where is the bid parameters being sent to bid adapters? I mean where are you configuring the bids with the bidder parameters?

Comment: Do you mean sth like that? http://prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/multi-format-example.html. I don't sure that I need write it and don't know where

Comment: It looks like you might be using an AMP page? If that's the case, Prebid.js won't work on a AMP page.